# Get text of the node

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In an ASP.NET application I have a IreeView.

Here is one of the nodes in the view:

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap;">
<input id="TreeView1n10CheckBox" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="TreeView1n10CheckBox">
<a id="TreeView1t10" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(TreeView1_Data, this,'TreeView1t10');" href="javascript:__doPostBack('TreeView1','sPreAnalytical\\Test Requisitions\\2 Specimens: 1 Req')" class="TreeView1_0">2 Specimens: 1 Req</a>
```

As you can see it is a checkbox and there is text after it `'TreeView1','sPreAnalytical\\Test Requisitions\\2 Specimens: 1 Req'`

How do I get the text `2 Specimens: 1 Req'` on the client side, and how do I modify this text using JavaScript and display the modified TreeView to the client?

this works beautifully:

```
function check_OnTreeNodeChecked(event) {
                  var TreeNode = event.srcElement || event.target;
                  if (TreeNode.tagName == "INPUT" && TreeNode.type == "checkbox") {
                      if (TreeNode.checked) {
                          var elNode = document.getElementById("TreeView1t10");
                          var sText = elNode.innerText || elNode.innerHTML;

                          alert(sText);
                          elNode.innerHTML = "Whatever you want";
                      }
                  }

              }
```

however since i need to modify the specific text next to the checkbox i need to be able to know which element id it was instead of implicitly specifying `var elNode = document.getElementById("TreeView1t10");`

**Question** how do i get the element id of the box that was checked?

Comment: I would suggest using jQuery, it allows easily traverse elements tree and access attributes/values easily. If you need to get inner text of this particular hyper link - access it by id `TreeView1t10`

Comment: please help me do taht i would love to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, it's quite simple...

```
var oldText = $('.TreeView1_0').text();
$('.TreeView1_0').text('new text here');
```

EDIT :

example here :  http://jsfiddle.net/shaneblake/ZG888/

Comment: ! awesome how do i set this up? i just make a reference to the library and thats it?

Comment: Yep, just add `<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`  (use latet version of jQuery)

Comment: @shane just tried it like this but not doing anything function check_OnTreeNodeChecked(event) {
                  var TreeNode = event.srcElement || event.target;
                  if (TreeNode.tagName == "INPUT" && TreeNode.type == "checkbox") {
                      if (TreeNode.checked) {
                          alert(TreeNode.id);
                      }
                  }
                  var oldText = $('.TreeView1_0').text();
                  $('.TreeView1_0').text('new text here');
              }

Comment: The ID of your node is "TreeView1t10" and not ".TreeView1_0". That's probably the reason.

Comment: i think you might not be asking all of the question at once...  could we see a little more code?  maybe an idea of the end result?

Comment: @shane i did what you said: function check_OnTreeNodeChecked(event) {
                  var TreeNode = event.srcElement || event.target;
                  if (TreeNode.tagName == "INPUT" && TreeNode.type == "checkbox") {
                      if (TreeNode.checked) {
                          var oldText = $('.TreeView1t10').text());
                          alert(oldText);
                          $('.TreeView1t10').text('new text here');
                      }
                  }
                 
              }

Comment: @shane it didnt like it at all :). yes when a user checks a certain checkbox in the treeview i would like an input from the user. the user will input something and that will be the new text of the corresponding text next to the checkbox

Comment: ah.  that's a lot more than you asked.   here's a jsFiddle that shows this much of it :  http://jsfiddle.net/shaneblake/ZG888/

Comment: @Krumelur, the code I provided works off the class name, not the ID.

Answer (score 3):

The text can be retrieved using:

```
var elNode = document.getElementById("TreeView1t10");
var sText = elNode.innerText || elNode.innerHTML;
```

Modify it using:

```
elNode.innerHTML = "Whatever you want";
```

To get the ID of the tree node in your click handler:

From the top of my head, untested, something like this will get you the tree node from the checkbox ID:

Checkbox ID = "TreeView1n10CheckBox"; replace "CheckBox" with nothing, so we have
"TreeView1n10". Then replace the "n" with "t" and we have "TreeView1t10", which is
the ID of the corresponding anchor tag.

```
var sTreeID = TreeNode.id.replace("CheckBox", "").replace("n", "t");
var elTreeNode = document.getElementById(sTreeID);
```

Comment: im doing this and its returning undefined var TreeNode = event.srcElement || event.target;
                  if (TreeNode.tagName == "INPUT" && TreeNode.type == "checkbox") {
                      if (TreeNode.checked) {
                          var elNode = document.getElementById(TreeNode.id);
                          var sText = elNode.innerText || elNode.innerHtml;
                          alert(sText);
                      }
                  }

Comment: There was a typo in my answer. It should be "innerHTML" and not "innerHtml". Try that.

Comment: thank you so much!!~ works beuatifully. can you please see my appended answer. i woudl like to know how to get the elementid  of the checkbox that was checked

Comment: But like others suggest by the way: get jQuery. It makes your life easier.

Comment: I think using javascript without jQuery is like driving around in a horse drawn carriage:  a very romantic notion, but not practical...   ;)

Answer (score 1):

With a tree view the class is probably utilized multiple times so accessing the specific element would be of more use.

```
var oldText = $('#TreeView1t10').html();
```

If you need to update all the trees text you can loop through them pretty simply as well.

```
$('.TreeView1t10').each(function() {
    var oldText = $(this).find('a').html();
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for the ansswer. can you please tell me if i do not know the elementid how can i get it? please see my edited answer